# How to detect mouseleave() on two elements at once? Angular4

Tags: angular, typescript

How or what will be the equivalent of doing something like this in angular4? how can we add multiple elements like in jquery? I try the settimeout in angular4, but for some reason doesn't work. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/pFTfm/195/

```
            var count = 0;
            var tolerance = 500;
            $('#d1, #d2').mouseenter(function(){
                count++;
                $('#d3').show();
            }).mouseleave(function(){
                count--;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (!count) {
                    $('#d3').hide();
                    }
                }, tolerance);
            });
```

**in angular**

```
isMouseEnter(e:number){
    this.dropdownId = e;
    this.toogleDropdown = true;

}

hideDropdown(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        if(!this.overElement){
            this.toogleDropdown = false;
        }
        else{
            this.toogleDropdown = true;
        }
    }, 100);

}
```

Comment: *I try the settimeout in angular4* - the question doesn't contain this part.

Comment: I add my angular function

Comment: this is my code you can test it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmt4bg

Comment: @SharmaVikramfor thx, however, some reason is not showing the 3rd div

Comment: stackbitz not working properly you are saying, please check one more time i have updated stackbitz with settimeout function

Comment: Sorry, is working now after I reload the page.

Comment: ok thanks now i am posting my answer please accept and upvote it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170351/discussion-between-sharma-vikram-and-jcdsr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the running code  [sample example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmt4bg)

> Html

```
 <div id="d1" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter('A')" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave('A')">div 1</div>
<div id="d2" (mouseenter)="mouseEnter('B')" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave('B')">div 2</div>
<div id="d3" [ngClass] ="{'hideDiv': div3}">
  div 3
</div>
```

> CSS

```
   p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
#d1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
}

#d2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    display: block;
}

#d3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    background: green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.hideDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

> Typescript Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
 div3: boolean = true;
  public mouseLeave(type) {
      if(type == 'A' || type == 'B') {
        this.showDiv(true);
      }
  }

  public mouseEnter(flag) {
    if(flag == 'A' || flag == 'B') {
        this.showDiv(false);
      }
  }

  public showDiv(flag) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.div3 = flag;
        }, 100);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use @HostListener and then use the $event.target to differentiate between your two elements:

```
@HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event.target'])
onLeave(): void {
  // Use your $event.target to differentiate the elements, then do actions
  // based on this.
}
```